# How to use OJDBC as an external jar to a Jython script when called from the command line

Tags: java, classpath, jython, ojdbc

I have a Jython script which  via the `java.sql` packages accesses an Oracle database. For this to work it needs the `ojdbc6.jar`.

When I run the script from the command line via

```
java -jar lib/jython.jar my-script.jy
```

the script starts up properly, but on the first SQL call it errors out with "*java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found*" indicating that it cannot find `ojdbc6.jar`.

How can I tell **with a terminal command** like the one above where the script can find the `ojdbc6.jar`?

#### PS:

Separately I set up the script inside an Eclipse Java project where I have added `ojdbc6.jar` (and of course `jython.jar`) as libraries. When I use a little wrapper Java class which instantiates a `PythonInterpreter` and calls the script via `PythonInterpreter.execfile` everything works fine: 
The script executes the SQL statements and gets the data from the Oracle database as expected. So clearly the Java project tells the script correctly where `ojdbc6.jar` is. But how can I do the same on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

i use this jython code for MS SQL Connection

```
   import sys 
   sys.path.append("C:\\Libs\\MyJavaPackage.jar")
   sys.path.append("C:\\Libs\\mssql-jdbc.jar") 
   import MyJavaPackage.MySQLClass
   import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver // use same import for oracle driver
   temp = MyJavaPackage.MySQLClass() // new java class instance
   temp.mySQLfunc() // function that use SQL Driver
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! I tried adding the path of `ojdbc6.jar` to `sys.path`, but I still get the error message. Adding a (dummy) import `import com.oracle.jdbc.driver` error out with "ImportError: No module named jdbc". Very strange, because in Eclipse the project does run!